# Facebook og:image appears in debug, post, newsfeed, timeline but missing in Likes > Favourites > Movies

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

All og data passes the fb debug linter.
All og data shows in posts, newsfeed and timeline.

but in

Likes > Favourites > Movies

Whilst the title and link for the like appears the og:image does not show.

You can test the following pages for this here:

http://www.globaltimoto.com/level-1/

**However**

If I follow the steps above, but at step 8 instead of entering the full uri.

I enter without the trailing slash:

http://www.globaltimoto.com/level-1/level-2/level-3/level-4/level-5

The browser attempts to load and the server does a 301 redirect to the same uri with trailing slash (as we would expect a server to do).

Now although the browser has arrived at the same page with trailing / the fb behaviour after liking the page is different.

By entering without the trailing slash the og:image now also appears in Likes > Favourites > Movies.

This is frustrating.

Either with or without the / the image should still show. It is particularly odd that the correct behaviour occurs without the / instead of with the /.

How can I achieve consistent behaviour **with** the trailing slash ?

Comment: has no one else experienced this strange behaviour ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since posting this query 4 days ago, I checked the status and reproduced the issue consistently.

Today however something has changed since I checked last (yesterday). I can no longer repro this bug. My og:image now appears in all expected locations post, newsfeed, wall, likes.

I can only presume fb made a change to the way things work at their end.

Comment: I face a similar issue. Image does not show up on the wall even thgouh debugger shows it. Can you please reopen the bug? I think I don't have access to 'submit bugs'. My page : www.rangde.org/marathon

Comment: @TJ- The bug on the fb site was closed and I am unable to re-open it. I have been finding that this issue is now intermittent and so not really solved. You will need to open a new bug with fb directly at: developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: thanks @timoto. It's just that it seems to me that I don't have permissions to file a bug.

Comment: perhaps you need to register a website or application at fb before you can post a bug.